# query to get most matched likes first in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table like:

**user :**

```
uid | course_id | subjects
---------------------------
1   | 1         | html,php
2   | 1         | java,html,sql
3   | 1         | java
4   | 1         | fashion,html,php,sql,java
```

I want to run a query which can return most liked subjects in query and then second most and so on...

For Example :

```
select * from user where subjects like '%java%' or '%php%' or '%html%';
```

this query will return data like this:

```
uid | course_id | subjects
---------------------------
2   | 1         | java,html,sql
3   | 1         | java
4   | 1         | fashion,html,php,sql,java
```

but i want output like this :

```
    uid | course_id | subjects
    ---------------------------
    4   | 1         | fashion,html,php,sql,java
    2   | 1         | java,html,sql
    1   | 1         | html,php
    3   | 1         | java
```

so the most matched subjects 1st then 2nd most matched subjects and so on....
Is there any modification in my query so that i can get this type of sorted output.

Comment: So you want to order by number of subjects separated by comma?

Comment: normalization anyone?

Comment: why record with uid = 1 not in result set?

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan : sorry, my mistake. but now its ok

Comment: no. it is not. Mysql is not taking that. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc793/19

Answer (score 2):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your `user` table. Then you can select normally.

It should look like this

```
uid | course_id | subjects
---------------------------
1   | 1         | html
1   | 1         | php
2   | 1         | java
2   | 1         | html
2   | 1         | sql
3   | 1         | java
...
```

or better introduce an new table `subjects` and then make a mapping table called `course_subjects`

```
subject
id | name
------------
1  | html
2  | sql
3  | java
...

course_subjects
uid | course_id | subject_id
---------------------------
1   | 1         | 1
1   | 1         | 2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you want your results, it looks like you want to order by the number of `subjects` (or tags) within `subject`. This can be accomplished by counting the number of `,` (commas).

The way to count the number of occurances of a character is to subtract the original length by the length when the character is removed.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   USER 
WHERE  subjects LIKE '%java%' 
        OR '%php%' 
        OR '%html%' 
ORDER  BY ( Length(subjects) - Length(Replace(subjects, ',', '')) ) DESC;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc793/4

**Result:**

```
UID COURSE_ID   SUBJECTS
4   1           fashion,html,php,sql,java
2   1           java,html,sql
3   1           java
```

**Note:**
As juergen says it is a bad idea to store multiple values in one column.

Answer (score 1):

With MyISAM storage engine you can do match against.

The simplest example:

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH (subjects) AGAINST ('java php html') AS relevance
FROM `user`
WHERE MATCH (subjects) AGAINST ('java php html')
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

In MySQL 5.6 full-text search is available with InnoDB too but needs a bit extra to make it work. For more info checkout the following post: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/04/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/

Comment: You don't need the comma after `relevance,`. Also, for some reason results are weird.. see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48b23/4

Comment: About the results in depends highly on what mode you are using (DEFAULT, BOOLEAN, NATURAL LANGUAGE). In this case BOOLEAN MODE gives better results, indeed. (SQLFiddle updated)

Thank you for pointing it out!